# Vim NERDTree: How to delete multiple files at once?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is possible to delete multiple files in VIM ERDTree?
I know the delete node command is m(show menu),d(delete node),y(delete?).
If I want to delete multiple files, I have to input m,d,y command many times.
Can I select many nodes and input delete command once to delete multiple files?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest netrw-s are using the COMSPEC environment variable with /c and move (and copy, for copying).  Should work more often under Windows without the user needing to specify a move and/or copy executable command.  Please upgrade your netrw to http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW ; as of now its up to v153f.

Comment: For Windows neovim users, there is a [blocking bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6695) preventing from using netrw or vim-dirvish.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, NERDTree doesn't let you select multiple nodes so I believe you can't do what you want with that plugin.

However, vim comes by default with another plugin which does *a lot* more than NERDTree called netrw: `:help netrw`.

With netrw, deleting multiple files is done like that:

```
mf
(navigation)
mf
...
D
```

Comment: I would recommend doing that kind of file manipulation from the shell or a real file explorer, though.

Comment: Thank you so much. These commands were workable. But I cannot move multiple files.
I used gvim 7.3 on Windows 7. Then keyin "mm" command to move my marked files. And I got an error message "(netrw) command<move> is not executable!". I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: It looks like netrw not being able to execute the external command for whatever reason. You should contact the author.